# Menu Item in Joomla 2.5.8

Tags: joomla, menu, joomla2.5, menuitem

I was earlier using Joomla 2.5.7 and in menu I have option as Menu Item association in Menu manager. However when I update to 2.5.8, I don't see that option. Any idea how to do menu item association in Joomla 2.5.8?

Comment: Try having a look at this, it might help: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2688496

Comment: @Lodder : thanks... can you provide this as answer so that I can accept you?

Comment: @Lodder : I have two languages as English and Arabic. I want to set Arabic as default. how to do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To set the default language to Arabic, go to you Joomla backend. Then, on the top menu, go to **Extensions >> Language Manager**, then select the Arabic language and click **default** in the top right.

My above explanation is how it's always done using the default Joomla language manager. [Here](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/language/change-site-language) is the same method but with screenshots:

As for the Menu Item association, see if the information on this link helps:

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2688496

It's for Joomla 1.7 but might also apply to you.

Hope this helps

Comment: I am done with menu item associations and its working. just default language is not working

Comment: try setting Arabic as your default language for your profile. also, are you using JoomFish or the default Joomla language manager?

Comment: well the way it works is how I showed you. I Also provided a link in my answer which shows is the same method but with screenshot, so it might be a little more help. As said in my last comment, try setting the default language in your profile to Arabic.